# How to add action to buttons in Alert in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, uialertviewdelegate

I am beginner level programmer. I am trying to add action to buttons on Alert, but it doesn't work. I just want to test if the alert button choice can change the text in label, but it doesn't work. Of course I can see the alert and buttons well, but nothing happens after clicking the button.

```
@IBOutlet var statusLabelAlert : UILabel

var alertTest = UIAlertView()

@IBAction func alertButton(sender : AnyObject) {

    alertTest.message = "Select one!"
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("1st")
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("2nd")
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("3rd")
    alertTest.title = "Test Alert"
    alertTest.show()

}
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
    switch buttonIndex{
    case 0:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "1st"
    case 1:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "2nd"
    case 2:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "3rd"
    default:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "error"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Is your clickedButtonAtIndex method calling? Put a breakpoint and debug the code.
You doesn't set the delegate of alertView.

```
@IBOutlet var statusLabelAlert : UILabel

var alertTest = UIAlertView()
alertTest.delegate = self   //set the delegate of alertView

@IBAction func alertButton(sender : AnyObject) {

alertTest.message = "Select one!"
alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("1st")
alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("2nd")
alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("3rd")
alertTest.title = "Test Alert"
alertTest.show()

}
func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){
switch buttonIndex{
case 0:
    statusLabelAlert.text = "1st"
case 1:
    statusLabelAlert.text = "2nd"
case 2:
    statusLabelAlert.text = "3rd"
default:
    statusLabelAlert.text = "error"
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to set the delegate of the alert view:

```
alertTest.delegate = self
```

`UIAlertView` uses the [delegate pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html) which means it calls methods on its delegate to achieve certain things or notify of events. With `UIAlertView`, one of those events is when the user taps a button. For the alert view to know who to tell about a user's tap, you must specify a delegate that implements the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol. Your code implements the protocol but it never tells the alert that you want to be its delegate so you never receive the method call.

Answer (score 3):

```
@IBOutlet var statusLabelAlert : UILabel
var alertTest = UIAlertView()
@IBAction func alertButton(sender : AnyObject)
{
    alertTest.delegate = self
    alertTest.message = "Select one!"
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("1st")
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("2nd")
    alertTest.addButtonWithTitle("3rd")
    alertTest.title = "Test Alert"
    alertTest.show()

}

func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
{
    switch buttonIndex
    {
        case 0:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "1st"
        case 1:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "2nd"
        case 2:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "3rd"
        default:
        statusLabelAlert.text = "error"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
IBOutlet var statusLabelAlert : UILabel

@IBAction func alertButton(sender : AnyObject) {

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "This is an Alert", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "1st", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
statusLabelAlert.text = "1st" 
}))

alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "2nd", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action: UIAlertAction!) in
statusLabelAlert.text = "2nd" 
}))

self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

If you don't want to do sth when the button is pressed:

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is for iOS 8 you should switch to UIAlertController and UIAlertAction. The UIAlertAction contains what the button should do.